# Moving children of a container (defined in MXML) inside an "inner container"

Tags: apache-flex, mxml, components, containers

I'm currently working on a custom component which extends Canvas (let's call it SuperCanvas) ; it's basically a container that let you zoom & pan its contents.

It would be too long to explain why, but I can't use scrollRect, so I was forced to declare a Canvas object (called *innerCanvas*)... inside my SuperCanvas (I know, not very nice =/)

**I would like to know if there's a proper way to "redirect" the creation of my component's children in this canvas.**

Let me explain:

```
<comp:SuperCanvas id="superCanvas">
   <mx:Image id="img" source="image.jpg"/>
   <mx:Label id="lbl" text="Sample"/>
</comp:SuperCanvas>
```

With this, img and lbl are added to my SuperCanvas. I want them to be added to *superCanvas.innerCanvas* instead.

I can't override the add/removeChild methods to do the "redirection", since I won't be able to add this *innerCanvas*...

So I tried this :

```
<comp:SuperCanvas>
   <comp:innerCanvas>
      <mx:Image id="img" source="image.jpg"/>
      <mx:Label id="lbl" text="Sample"/>
   </comp:innerCanvas>
</comp:SuperCanvas>
```

But Flex complains that "*In initializer for 'contents': type mx.controls.Image is not assignable to target type mx.containers.Canvas*". I read I could use an array of UIComponents with a *[ArrayElementType]* metatag, and manually instanciate objects, but I I'm looking for a simplier (and probably proper) solution.

I also saw the childDescriptor property (which contains descriptions for every child defined in the MXML file), but it's read-only, so I can't pass it to my *innerCanvas*.

If I'm not clear enough, do not hesitate to ask me precisions, english isn't my native tongue, so it's pretty hard to explain things well =/

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm totally stuck.

---

EDIT:
My SuperCanvas class (minus the imports and the zoom & pan logic that doesn't matter here) :

```
public class SuperCanvas extends Canvas
{
    public innerCanvas:Canvas = new Canvas();

    public function SuperCanvas()
    {
      super();
      addChild( innerCanvas );
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the definition of the classes SuperCanvas, innerCanvas ?

Comment: I edited my question with the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [blog entry](http://blog.jocabola.com/nested-child-nodes-within-custom-mxml-components-in-flex/) details an approach where you add components to the SuperCanvas, but then move them all to the inner canvas after creation.  So that's one workaround.

Alternatively, you could set the `DefaultProperty` to be a `dataProvider`-type object, and then add things to the inner canvas from there, rather than making them children of the SuperCanvas first.

Addition:

I ran across this [blog entry](http://jessewarden.com/2008/01/when-you-hit-a-design-brick-wall-in-flex.html) which, among other things, talks about the [`Panel`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/containers/Panel.html) component and how it handles this problem.  You  might look at it and at the `Panel` source code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!
I tried the solution from jocabola.blog, which seems pretty nice. However, with this approach, I can't access to my *innerCanvas* CREATION_COMPLETE event (which I need to retrieve its width and height).
In the end of the addComponents() method, my *innerCanvas* width and height are both equal to 0.

Comment: Hmm.  Can you call `validateNow` on the [inner or outer] container to force it through the motions?

Comment: I tried that, but it seems I face another issue now ; the width and height properties remains equal to 0. The problem is that the Image components I put inside my canvas haven't finished loading at this point. I overrided the Image class in order to dispatch its creationComplete event only after loading is complete (when its width & height properties are available). But I came to understand that Flex containers do not wait for their child to dispatch their own creationComplete event to dispatch their (not sure I'm very clear, sorry =/) By the way, it's another issue. Thanks a lot!